# Debconf dialog during .deb installation

Tags: ubuntu, deb, debconf

I was successfully able to create a .deb installation file for Ubuntu, but I need user input to complete the configuration for the post install script. These questions are dynamic and based on the interfaces a user has on their computer.

Is there a way to prompt the user with questions that have dynamic answers (i.e.- a list of interfaces on their computer) during the install process in Ubuntu Software Center using debconf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it. In the templates file you create a substitution variable and fill it inside the configuration file.

Templates File:

```
Template: pkg/interfaces
Type: select
Choices: ${choices}
Description: .....
```

Config File:

```
declare -a options;
count=0;

## Get interfaces from the operating system
for interface in $(ip link show | awk '/^[0-9]/ {print $2;} ' | sed 's/:$//');
do
    if [ $interface != "lo" ] && [ $interface != "" ] ;
    then
        options[$count]=$interface;
        count=$((count+1));
    fi
done

# Set the choices the user has
db_subst pkg/outface choices $options
```